# unable to extract ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Right now I'm trying to change some data in a database by updating an entity with a query, but I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

This is my Mapping controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/vacChange", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changedVac(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true)  Integer id,
                     @RequestParam(value = "ort", required = true) String ort,
                     @RequestParam(value = "bereich", required = true) String bereich,
                     @RequestParam(value = "beschreibung", required = true) String beschreibung){
vacService.changeVacancyByID(id,gehalt,ort,bereich,beschreibung);


return "vacAdmin";
}
```

This is the service class method I use :

```
void changeVacancyByID(Integer id, String gehalt,String ort,String bereich,String beschreibung);

}
```

The implementation for the service method:

```
public void changeVacancyByID(Integer id, String gehalt,String ort,String bereich,String beschreibung){
    System.out.println("Edit method called");
    VacancyEntity vacEntity = vacancyRepository.findOneById(id);
    vacancyRepository.updateAttributes(id,gehalt,ort,bereich,beschreibung);

}
```

Well and this is the query I use:

```
@Transactional
@Query (value = "UPDATE vacancy SET salary=?2, location=?3,functionality=?4, description=?5 WHERE id = ?1  ", nativeQuery = true)
void updateAttributes(Integer id, String gehalt, String ort, String bereich, String beschreibung);
```

Additionally VacancyEntity class, getter and setter are also included :

```
@Entity(name = "vacancy")
public class VacancyEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
/**
 * the vacancy identifier.
 * "@Id": id is key attribute in database table vacancy.
 * "@GenerartedValue": new inserted vacancies will get an id automatically.
 * "@Column": name of colum in database table vacancy.
 */
private Integer id;

@Lob 
@Column(name = "description")
/**
 * The vacancy description, a full text.
 */
private String description;

@Column(name = "functionality")
/**
 * The vacancy functionality.
 */
private String functionality;

@Column(name = "titel")
/**
 * The vacancy titel.
 */
private String titel;

@Column(name = "salary")
/**
 * The vacancy salary.
 */
private String salary;

@Column(name = "contracttype")
/**
 * Type of Contract for the Vacancy. For further info go to "Mögliche Filter für Stellen und Bewerbungen.pdf" (section: Vertragsart) in the wiki"
 */
private String contractType;

@Column(name = "employmenttype")
/**
 * Type of Employment. For further info go to "Mögliche Filter für Stellen und Bewerbungen.pdf" (section: Beschäftigungsverhältnis) in the wiki
 */
private String employmentType;

@Column(name = "interestgroup")
/**
 * The vacancy's interest group. For further info go to "Mögliche Filter für Stellen und Bewerbungen.pdf" (section: Interessengruppe) in the wiki
 */
private String interestGroup;

@Column(name = "abstractdescription")
/**
 * A brief description of the occupation. 
 * No Lob: please restrict the number of characters.
 */
private String abstractDescription;


@Column(name = "travel")

/**
 * 
 */
private String travel;


@Column(name = "requirements")
/**
 * Requirements, the applicants have to fullfill.
 */
private String requirements;

@Column(name = "location")
/**
 * The location of the vacancy. (Cities e.g. Bielefeld, Berlin, München...)
 */
private String location;

@Column(name = "commencement")
/**
 * The date, at which the applicant can begin to work.
 */
private String commencement;

@Column(name = "duration")
/**
 * The time period of employment.
 */
private String duration;

@Column(name = "tasks")
/**
 * The tasks the applicant can expect.
 */
private String tasks;


@Column(name = "referencecode")
/**
 * The reference Code.
 */
private String referenceCode;

@Column(name = "employmentlevel")
/**
 * The level of employment (e.g. full time, part time...)
 */
private String employmentLevel;

@Column(name = "buisnesstravel")
/**
 * Information as to the necessity of buisness trips.
 */
private String buisnessTravel;

public VacancyEntity() {
}
/**
 * Constructor of class VacancyEntity.
 * @param id, the given id
 * @param titel, the given titel
 * @param functionality, the given functionality
 * @param salary, the given salary
 * @param description , the given description
 * @param contractType, the given type of contract
 * @param employmentType, the given type of employment
 * @param interestGroup, the given interest group
 * @param abstractDescription, the given short version of the description
 * @param requirements, the given requirements.
 * @param location, the given location of the vacancy.
 * @param commencement, the given date, at which the applicant can begin to work.
 * @param duration, the given time period of employment.
 * @param tasks, the given tasks.
 * @param referenceCode, the given reference code.
 * @param employmentLevel, the given level of employment.
 * @param buisnessTravel, the given necessity of buisness trips.
 */
public VacancyEntity(Integer id, 
                     String titel,  
                     String functionality, 
                     String salary, 
                     String description, 
                     String contractType, 
                     String employmentType, 
                     String interestGroup, 
                     String abstractDescription,
                     String requirements, 
                     String location, 
                     String commencement, 
                     String duration, 
                     String tasks,
                     String referenceCode, 
                     String employmentLevel, 
                     String buisnessTravel)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.functionality = functionality;
    this.titel = titel;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.contractType = contractType;
    this.employmentType = employmentType;
    this.interestGroup = interestGroup;
    this.abstractDescription = abstractDescription;
    this.requirements = requirements;
    this.location = location;
    this.commencement = commencement;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.tasks = tasks;
    this.referenceCode = referenceCode;
    this.employmentLevel = employmentLevel;
    this.buisnessTravel = buisnessTravel;
}
```

This is a the full stacktrace:

```
Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement:
UPDATE vacancy SET salary=?, location=?,functionality=?, description=? WHERE id = ?   [90002-185]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
at org.h2.command.Prepared.query(Prepared.java:212)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:90)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:197)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:108)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1869)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:142)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:96)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:337)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:105)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.updateAttributes(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.updateAttributes(Unknown Source)
at de.unibielefeld.techfak.tdpe.jsp.domain.VacancyServiceImpl.changeVacancyByID(VacancyServiceImpl.java:129)
at de.unibielefeld.techfak.tdpe.jsp.VacancyController.changedVac(VacancyController.java:234)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`UPDATE` operation doesn't return anything (you can try running the query in your favorite DB client), so spring fails when trying to construct a `VacancyEntity` from the result of your update query. You also need to add `@Modifying` to the query [because it's an updating query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries).

To fix the issue, change your repository to this:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query (value = "UPDATE vacancy SET salary=?2, location=?3,functionality=?4, description=?5 WHERE id = ?1  ", nativeQuery = true)
void updateAttributes(Integer id, String gehalt, String ort, String bereich, String beschreibung);
```

Comment: This should work, you should clear the project, rebuild, redeploy and retest. And if the error still occurs, post a **full** stacktrace (and also post code for `VacancyEntity`).

Comment: Still not working, I added now the full stacktrace and the VacancyEntity code

Comment: Try adding `@Modifying` to the query.

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot. Could you explain why it was necessary?